# Extracting subject/object in Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp, spacy

I am very new to working with Spacy in Python and I have an issue - when identifying the subject/object, Spacy doesn’t label the whole proper noun as the subject/object. For example when working with two similar nouns in the same context (e.g. John Doe and John Smith) spacy confuses Doe and Smith because they are both Johns.

I was wondering how I could solve this issue. For example by injecting something in the lines of “if Doe follows John, then John Doe is the subject, and if Smith follows the word John, then John Smith is the subject”?

Here's what I have so far

```
if lang == 'en':    
dir_path = r'/User/news/articles/en'
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
#if name comes after these words he is most likely the object
indObjCombinations = re.compile(r'\b(with|for|against|to|from|without|between)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE)
passiveCombinations = re.compile(r'\b(by)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE)
objCombinations =  re.compile(r'\b(received|receives|welcomes|welcomed)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE)

subjCombinations = re.compile(r'\b(%s)(?:\W+\w+){0,1}?\W+(in)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE)
subjCombinations_andName = re.compile(r'\b(and)(\W+\w+){0,3}\W+(%s)(\W+\w+){0,3}\W+(are)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE )
subjCombinations_nameAnd = re.compile(r'\b(%s)(\W+\w+){0,3}\W+(and)(\W+\w+){0,3}\W+(are)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE )
subjBeginning = re.compile(r'\b^(%s)(\W+\w+){0,1}\W*(:)\b' % '|'.join(names),re.IGNORECASE )


def getSubsFromConjunctions(subs):
moreSubs = []
for sub in subs:
# rights is a generator
    rights = list(sub.rights)
    rightDeps = {tok.lower_ for tok in rights}

   if lang == 'en':
        if "and" in rightDeps:
            moreSubs.extend([tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in SUBJECTS or tok.pos_ == "NOUN"])
            if len(moreSubs) > 0:
                moreSubs.extend(getSubsFromConjunctions(moreSubs))

  def getObjsFromConjunctions(objs):
moreObjs = []
for obj in objs:
# rights is a generator
    rights = list(obj.rights)
    rightDeps = {tok.lower_ for tok in rights}
    if lang == 'en':
        if "and" in rightDeps:
            moreObjs.extend([tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS or tok.pos_ == "NOUN"])
            if len(moreObjs) > 0:
                 moreObjs.extend(getObjsFromConjunctions(moreObjs))
```

Comment: This is not a programming but a design question, you might want to ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Is it on purpose that you are doing this task with regular expressions, i.e. rule-based? It might be relevant if you want something simple, but there are other options with ML. This particular problem is called [semantic role labeling (SRL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling).

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the DependencyMatcher with `merge_entities` or `merge_noun_chunks`. The approach you have now with regular expressions is hard to understand and I don't think it will work well. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#dependencymatcher